# color the background of every other table row styled components

Tags: html, css, html-table, styled-components

I can't seem to change the background color of every other row via styled components. What am I doing wrong?

I am adding the :nth-child()  on the styled.tr

```
export const TR = styled.tr`
    text-align: center;
    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
      }
`;
```

```
    <StyledTable>
        <THead>
            <TR>
                <TH>ID</TH>
                <TH>NAME</TH>
                <TH>PHONE</TH>
            </TR>
        </THead>
        <TBody>
            {usersData?.map((user) => (
                <TR
                    key={user.id}
                >
                    <TD>{user.id}</TD>
                    <TD>{user.name}</TD>
                    <TD>{user.phone}</TD>
                </TR>
            ))}
        </TBody>
    </StyledTable>
```

[image]

Comment: maybe the problem is trying to use a css rule (with selector) in the inline style. Can't you just add it in your css instead? or maybe try to make it like `:nth-child(even)` instead of `tr:nth-child(even)`

Comment: Ah, :nth-child(even) worked!